# assigning value to jquery parameter wrapped inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have something like this

```
function custom_jsonResult_ajaxCall(murl){
    $.ajax({
        url: murl;
        success: function(response) {
            var jresult = JSON.parse(response);
            return jresult
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

from the chrome debugger it seems like

```
url: murl;
```

is an incorrect way of assigning the variable `murl` to `url` ?

What is the correct way of assigning a variable in this case ?

Comment: How do you debug your code for simple errors? What do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
              url: murl,
```

not

```
              url: murl;
```

Because it is a couple of key-value in literal object

Comment: oh ok because this is all in a dictionary ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Chrome inspect to debug your code.

Try this:

```
function custom_jsonResult_ajaxCall(murl){
    $.ajax({
        url: murl,
        success: function(response) {
            var jresult = JSON.parse(response);
            return jresult
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```